# VScode compile C++ on windows the exe not found

Tags: debugging, compiler-errors, g++, exe, visual-studio-code

I want to ask how to debug a simple hello world output from a C++ file, on the **launch file** I have to put the executable but I have only created a C++ file, how to compile it, I have tried everything, please help.

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "g++",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    // compiles and links with debugger information
    "args": ["-g", "-o", "main.exe", "main.cpp"],
    // without debugger information
    // "args": ["-o", "hello.exe", "hello.cpp"],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

Comment: And what is the output? Something like 'g++ not found'?

Comment: Did you try to follow this guide? https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/launch.md

Comment: The above link is update now: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question but here's a clear explanation for anyone in future.

Issue is that the debugger was looking for a.exe but your build file will probably be named different.

[image]

Changing the values of `program` variable to `"${workspaceFolder}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"` will fix this issue. This should be in the `tasks.json` and the `launch.json`.

This env variable takes care that the right name is substituted. Now set a breakpoint and press `f5`.

Further details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47872250/4168707) and [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference).

Here's a full preview of a working `launch.json`

```
"configurations": [
{
    "name": "(gdb) Launch",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
    "args": [],
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "cwd": "C:\\MinGw\\bin",
    "environment": [],
    "externalConsole": false,
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGw\\bin\\gdb.exe",
    "setupCommands": [
        {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        },
        {
            "description":  "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
            "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        }
    ]
}
```

And a full preview of `tasks.json`.

```
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
```

**NOTE:** As explained [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/449) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57498269/4168707), you might want to set `"externalConsole": true` if your code needs input from user.