# Cant run C++ onto console in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, console

Every time I click F5 to debug or run my code to console, I only receive an error message and im not so sure what to do. Im new to VSCode and help is highly appreciated.

I get an error saying: launch program " does not exist

Any advice as to what I should do? My OS is windows 10.

I've tried installing code runner and reinstalling visual studio all together. Though I cant find anything on the internet for any information.

Comment: Maybe the path is wrong to the executable if you verified that the executable exists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't compile code "launch: program <program\_path> does not exist "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47872250/cant-compile-code-launch-program-program-path-does-not-exist)