# Automating GCC Compiler arguments to create easier compilations - Windows OS?

Tags: gcc, makefile, compilation

### Goal

When I run the command:
`gcc -ggdb -std=c99 -Wall -Werror hello.c -lcs50 -o test.exe` from the root directory
I am able to build the test.exe file and when I run test.exe all is well (thanks to [this post by Manohar Reddy Poreddy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50658089/15592981))

However all of those flags are a little bit cumbersome and I think it would great to condense them into a 'make' command or similar. How would I do this on windows?

### Context

GCC, G++ and GDB all seem to be correctly linked (I used chocolatey which paths everything automatically)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found what I was looking for.

I hope this answer can help others. Turns out the utility is called 'make' (no surprises). In your directory you essentially create a 'makefile' where you can include your command line arguments which saves on repeated typing in the command line for each compile.

Here is [an excellent response on how to install 'make' for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32127632/15592981) and was perfect for my use case as a Chocolatey user.

I also found this [resource which helps newcomers begin to get their head round GCC](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html) which I highly recommend if you're coming into this like I was and felt completely out of your depth.