# ENOENTBuild finished with error(s) - VS Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, build

I'm trying to compile a `.c` file that's an example from an API. That API also has a `.lib` and a `.h`. It's my first time using VS Code. My file structure is as follows:
[image: File structure]

I have been fighting with the compiler to be able to link the `.lib`. Since, at the beginning, following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50658089/21186572), the functions used were all "undefined reference".

As a result, I tried to follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59600574/21186572) instead.

My `tasks.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Compiler",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-c",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\example.c",
                "-IC:\\myproj"
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Linker",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceFolder}\\example.o",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\bin\\example.exe",
                "-LC:\\myproj",
                "-lmingw32",
                "-lSDL2main",
                "-lSDL2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Build Example",
            "dependsOn": [
                "Compiler",
                "Linker"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And my `c_cpp_properties.json`:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "C:\\myproj","${workspaceFolder}"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
            },
            "includePath": [
                "C:\\myproj","${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

After trying to build (`Shift`+`Ctrl`+`B`), I get this:

```
Starting build...
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\myproj\example.c -o C:\myproj\example.exe
spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe ENOENTBuild finished with error(s).
```

What should I do?